# Uncaught ReferenceError: Imported Class is not defined

Tags: javascript, class

While extending from a parent class I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: `Plottable` is not defined

**Place.js:**

```
import {Plottable} from "../Plottable.js";

console.log(Plottable.word);
export class Place extends Plottable {}
```

**Plottable.js:**

```
import {Place} from "./Place/Place.js";
export class Plottable extends Thing {}
```

What also confuses me is that, for some reason, no errors or warnings are thrown in my IDE, (Intellij IDEA).

**Edit:**
Apparently, `import {Place} from "./Place/Place.js";` in `Plottable.js` is causing the problem. Why is this?

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(Plottable.word);`?

Comment: can you describe your file structure? where is Place.js and where is Plottable?

Comment: i tried `console.log(Plottable.word);`, and it gave the same error as extending the class. The file structure is fine with the folder containing Place in the same directory as the one containing Plottable.

Comment: Should be easy enough to debug now that you've found the root cause... is there a file (relative to `Plottable.js`) `./Place/Place.js`? Does it export a `Place` symbol, ie `export Place ...`?

Comment: I think the problem has to do with circular dependencies. I'll just create a third class to avoid that.